# Increase amount of reviewers per review

Tags: feature-request

Right now when something is reviewed, it's reviewed by ONE person only, then it's done.

Instead that number should be increased to something like THREE.

**Example:**
*User1234 posts his first answer where he writes "I like shoes".*

*Experienced user WeirdPhilosopher reviews the post and tells the user "you need a reference to you liking shoes". He then clicks done! Review 1 done*

*Experienced user Fabulous reviews the post and agrees with WeirdPhilosopher, and adds a link to the [FAQ] and [help]. He clicks done! Review 2 done*

*Experienced user Cskbinnx reviews the post and agrees with the two first reviews but also flags the post as not an answer, and tells User1234 that he did not answer the question. He clicks done. Review 3 done.*

*Now the post disappears for requiring review.*

My example was a pretty stupid situation, but WeirdPhilosopher and Fabulous missed things during their reviews so having someone more review as well doesn't really hurt. And while this post was easy, more difficult situations might happen, especially when it comes to edits.
This would also mean no one can do an edit without being peer reviewed first, which I think is a really good system.

This would ensure things stay at a high quality, even if it's not a full peer review board.

Comment: WeirdPhilosopher lol!

Comment: You're just jealous there wasn't a Marmaladeegc.

Comment: Which reviews are you talking about? The "one reviewer per item" thing is not true for some review types. Items in the Suggested Edits review queue get reviewed by two or more higher rep users.  Close/Reopen queues have fairly involved formulas as to how long they remain in the queue. Are you only referring to First Posts review queue?  Low Quality Posts review queue? Late Answers?  Some of those have the potential to be reviewed by more than one person already, too, iirc.

Comment: I see, since I only have <2000 I don't know how the other queues work, only Late answer and First post. And from what I have seen it's only 1 review on those, and I got the feeling it was the same for edits.

Comment: I had asked about this as I thought the thresholds were higher than one user for most queue, but actually most posts can be removed from a queue by a single user: in the low quality queue it takes one "looks good", first post/late answer anything but skip is enough, edits dequeue from close queue.

Comment: Let's increase the number of reviewers first, reviews per reviewer second, and reviewers per review third!

Comment: @Sklivvz to increase the number of reviewers you need to increase the reviewers per review. One active person can handle pretty much all the things to review easily, and nothing ensures he does it well.

Comment: Keep in mind that the review queue system is relatively new, and was primarily designed to help supplement the most common form of review: people going through the list of questions to see what is new/active.  In other words, just because something drops out of the review queue does not mean people won't see the activity and review it outside of the queue system.